# N-channel MOSFET connection

Tags: mosfet, switches

I'm studying this circuit below which in fact uses a N-channel MOSFET in a power line, with source at the supply voltage and drain at the load.

Why the source is the input supply voltage and not the drain?

[LTC4040 datasheet](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4040)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because there is a parasitic diode inside the MOSFET and if you put it the other way it would not allow the input voltage to be much less than the output voltage (even on standby).

The MOSFET is equally happy allowing current to flow either way, even though it seems to be operating 'backward' when the 4.5V supply is present.

[image]

Edit: See the waveform during transition to standby:

If the MOSFET was the other way around, the standby power would backfeed other loads that may be connected to the 4.5V input supply.

This is the feature mentioned on the front page of the datasheet:

**Input Disconnect Switch Isolates Input During Backup**

[image]

Comment: But why it needs much less input voltage than the output voltage?

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: And as is logic Vin > 0 in backup mode isn't acceptable... Right?

Comment: Right, in many cases it's not acceptable.

Comment: @MrBit for the specific part it seems that Vin>0 is acceptable in backup mode. Excerpt from the datasheet: `When the input supply
falls below the PFI threshold, backup mode disconnects
the switches (MN1 and MN2) to isolate the system (V SYS )
from the input while the boost converter powers the system
load from the battery using the same external inductor, L1.`

Comment: @LorenzoDonati It's acceptable from the pov of the chip, but my point is that it is often unacceptable to have the backup battery/supply backfeeding other loads that happen to be connected to the Vin. Even if it's capable of supplying whatever is out there, it will drain the battery faster.

Comment: @Ah, OK. I misunderstood what you meant. Got it now. Although I think the OP maybe was worried that you need a complete Vin black out for that chip to be usable. Instead it seems it handles brownouts as well, since it isolates completely what lies before the MOSFET if it detects a Vin under that PFI threshold, if I understood its operations well.